# Bash regular expression: print all matches from string

Tags: bash

I have a $content variable which is a long string that contains the word "title" multiple times. How do I match title and print all of the matches in Bash regex?

```
[[ $content =~ title ]] && echo ${BASH_REMATCH}
```

This only prints the first match.

Comment: `BASH_REMATCH`'s elements are for backreferencing, not for multiple matches.

Comment: So how would I print all matches? Use awk or grep? I'm running grep on OSX so I really wouldn't like to use it: grep (BSD grep) 2.5.1-FreeBSD

Comment: `grep -o` no? What's the problem? Do you need access to perlre?

Comment: It doesn't seem like grep has access to + or parenthesis on the FreeBSD-version. I would also make some other matches than "title".

Comment: A failed attempt to continue playing: `c="t t t g g h h t t t t t o f"; [[ $c =~ ((t ))+ ]]; echo ${BASH_REMATCH[@]}; declare -p BASH_REMATCH`

Comment: Wait what? Parentheses and plus are part of ERE, and should be in any implementation of `grep -E`. Try `echo 'title turtle ' | /usr/bin/grep -oE '(t[a-z]+tle )+'`.

Comment: You're right. Im just dumb :)

Answer (score 1):

Can you give us the value of $content and also your desired output? It sounds like you need to do something like:

```
echo ${BASH_REMATCH[*]}
```

Comment: No, `BASH_REMATCH`'s elements are for backreferencing, not for multiple matches.